Error 400 - POST to upload file in bot framework emulator
I'm encountering an issue when attempting to upload large files (specifically, files of size 238MB and larger) in the Bot Framework Emulator. While smaller files are successfully uploaded and validated, attempting to upload files larger than approximately 234MB results in a 400 error with the following message:
message: "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
code: "ServiceError"
I've thoroughly checked my code, and it functions as expected with smaller files. However, when attempting to upload larger files, the error occurs consistently. Unfortunately, I'm unable to retrieve any error logs as the message doesn't even get sent and remains stuck in the "sending" state.
Could this issue be related to any limitations within the Bot Framework Emulator regarding file size? Or perhaps there's another aspect I might be overlooking? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Most services have a hard limit on the file or attachment size of an item to be uploaded onto their servers. Primarily, because it would be cost prohibitive to maintain a storage system to house an unknown amount of files that are each of an unknown size from an unknown number of users. So, generally speaking, if a user needs to upload a large file, then you need to implement your own storage to facilitate this.
In the case of DirectLine, the limit if 4 MB. You can reference this post for additional information.
